# Field equations in extended EH-GHY action. Is Schwarzschild a solution?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, variational-principle, action, boundary-terms

When taking the EH action, $$S_{EH} = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\int_M d^4x \sqrt{-g}R$$ and making a small variation in the metric while ignoring boundary terms, we obtain

$$\delta S_{EH} = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\int_M d^4x \sqrt{-g}\left(\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu}R -R^{\mu \nu}\right)\delta g_{\mu \nu} $$.

When looking for solutions we demand $\delta S = 0$, and so we get the vacuum Einstein field equations, $$\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu}R -R^{\mu \nu}=0$$ which the Schwarzschild metric satisfies. So far so good.

Now we want to add the GHY term to the action, $$S_{GHY} = \frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_{\partial M} d^3x \sqrt{-h}K$$ which will cancel out any boundary terms we neglected arbitrarily in the former variation. When varying the metric we obtain

$$\delta S_{EH+GBY} = \frac{1}{16\pi G}\int_M d^4x \sqrt{-g}(\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \nu}R -R^{\mu \nu})\delta g_{\mu \nu}\\ + \frac{1}{8\pi G}\int_{\partial M} d^3x \sqrt{-h}\frac{1}{2}( h^{\mu \nu}K -K^{\mu \nu})\delta g_{\mu \nu}$$

This gives a new set of field equations. My problem is that it seems to me the Schwarzschild metric is no longer a solution: we know the first term vanishes identically since it satisfies the original Einstein equations, so in order for it to be an extremal point of the metric, the second term also has to vanish identically. i.e., the coefficient of $\delta g_{\mu \nu}$ must vanish:

$$\sqrt{-h}\frac{1}{2}( h^{\mu \nu}K -K^{\mu \nu}) = 0.$$

Multiplying the equality by $g_{\mu \nu}$ and removing non-zero constants, we get

$$K=0,$$

which doesn't hold for a surface of constant radius embedded in the Schwarzschild metric. Even if we take Gibbons' and Hawking's normalization by subtracting a boundary term for the extrinsic curvature of the boundary embedded in flat space, we would get

$$K = K_0,$$

which still doesn't hold for a surface of constant radius.

Can anyone please tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: $\delta S_{EH+GBY}$ only contains the first term right? As you have mentioned the second term cancels the boundary terms. One ends up obtaining the same variation (and therefore equations of motion) as before.

Comment: I think the variation as i wrote it is correct. There was another part that came from the GHY term that cancelled out the EH boundary term. I'm pretty sure my mistake is simply that the second term vanishes since $\delta g_{\mu \nu}$ vanishes on the boundary. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that adding boundary terms to the action does not change the equations of motion! It merely changes the boundary conditions which you have to impose in order for the variational principle to yield the equations of motion.

That said, the role of the Gibbons-Hawking-York boundary term is **not** to cancel the all the surface integrals you obtain from varying the $S_{EH}$, as you have verified yourself. Rather, the addition of $S_{GHY}$ cancels the boundary terms involving $\delta( \partial_{\sigma}g_{\mu\nu})$. Hence the effect of adding $S_{GHY}$ is that you only need to require $\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ to vanish on the boundary, in order to obtain the Einstein equations. I.e. we only need to fix the metric on the boundary. Without $S_{GHY}$ you'd have to require the derivatives of $g_{\mu\nu}$ to be fixed on the boundary as well.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to say in my comment above. Thanks, Scrooge!